# Python - Select string from a list based on index number - index number entered via input

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, enumeration

I'm trying to help someone extract a list of facilities from a list without having to enter the full name of the facility.  Instead, I thought it would be easier to associate a number with each facility and allow the user to just enter the corresponding number to get the string.  For example, if I have a list of 'facility a', 'facility b', and 'facility c', if the user entered '0', 'facility a' would show up, 1 'facility b' would show up, etc.  I know my code is incorrect, but I am struggling to make this work based on the number a user enters through the input command.  See code below.

```
facilities = ['facility a', 'facility b', 'facility c']

for count, value in enumerate(facilities):
    j = (count, value)
    print(j) #This is just so the user can see all possible options in the list 

f = input('Please enter the corresponding number of the facility you want to select: ')

final_facility = facilities[f] # I know this doesn't work and it wants a number, not a string

print(final_facility)
```

Comment: `f = int(input(...))`?

Comment: `facilities[int(f)]`? wrapped it with try catch and show some nice error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the input is numeric and then convert it to an int. Like this:

```
facilities = ['facility a', 'facility b', 'facility c']

for count, value in enumerate(facilities):
    j = (count, value)
    print(j) #This is just so the user can see all possible options in the list 

f = input('Please enter the corresponding number of the facility you want to select: ')

final_facility = 'Please eneter a number' # Prints this if f is not numeric
if f.isnumeric():
    final_facility = facilities[int(f)] # I know this doesn't work and it wants a number, not a string

print(final_facility)
```

Answer (score 2):

Cast the input to a integer using `int`, like so:

`f = int(input('Please enter the corresponding number of the facility you want to select: '))`

To be precise, whenever you want to access the element at a index do, `int(f)` instead of directly passing `f`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `input()` returns a string. But, list indices can't be strings. So, it needs to be like this

```
f = int(input('Please enter the corresponding number of the facility you want to select: '))
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can automatically typecast your input as:
`f = int(input('Please ...'))`

Answer (score 2):

```
facilities = ['facility a', 'facility b', 'facility c']

for count, value in enumerate(facilities):
    j = (count, value)
    print(j) #This is just so the user can see all possible options in the list

f = input('Please enter the corresponding number of the facility you want to select: ')

final_facility = facilities[int(f)] # Pass int(f) instead of f

print(final_facility)
```

or

```
facilities = ['facility a', 'facility b', 'facility c']

for count, value in enumerate(facilities):
    j = (count, value)
    print(j) #This is just so the user can see all possible options in the list

f = int(input('Please enter the corresponding number of the facility you want to select: ')) # Typecast your input to int

final_facility = facilities[f] 

print(final_facility)
```

make sure to handle exceptions for ValueErrors.

Answer (score 1):

Just before final facility, write `f=int(f)`
That should solve it. Because, the user input, is by default a string in python, so now, we have typecasted the f to an integer which solves it.
Also try using dictionary which will remove this complete hassle altogether.
Also to get the answer,  after the for loop you can directly just write:
`print(facilities (int(f)))`.